# Express interval in C programming

Tags: c

How can I express that `K=1:N` i.e between `1` to `N`  in C programming?
I am new to C.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int N=length(x);
  float K=1:N;  
  printf("%f", K);
};
```

Comment: You can't. you need separate min and max (and possibly step) variables.

Comment: Well, you can use Matlab :)

Comment: you could define a simple struct `struct interval { unsigned long length; unsigned long index;};`

Comment: Thanks, now i found a tutorial by Kernighan and Ritchie http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html

Comment: int k;
int N;
for(k=1; k<=N; k=k+1)
printf("%d",k);

Comment: @user2240149 you should read the first few lines of that tutorial carefully. It says: "*Disclaimer: This “tutorial” is presented as a historical document, **not as a tutorial**.  Although it has lost little of its didactic value, **it describes a language that C compilers today do no longer understand**: the C of 1974, four years before Kernighan and Ritchie published the first edition of “The C Programming Language”.*" You should find a recent book. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most robust method would be to use an integer index and convert it to a float within the loop on each iteration:

```
int j;

for (j = 1 ; j <= N; ++j) // iterate integer j from 1 to N
{
    float K = (float)j;   // convert integer j to float K
    ...
}
```

Note that this is much safer than using a `float` as the loop variable, as it's not susceptible to rounding errors which can cause problems in testing for the loop termination condition.

Comment: Assuming a whole number or N, this certainly makes sense. He does have an `int` there for N, so I think its a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare K as integer

```
 int k;
```

and then use any of the loops 
**while or for loops**

**for-Loop:**

```
 for(k=1;k<=N;K++)  
    {
    printf("%d ",k);  
    //if you want to print or use in float  use casting  printf("%f ",(float) k);
    }
```

**while-Loop:**

```
k=1;
while(k<=N)
{
printf("%d ",k);  
//if you want to print or use in float  use casting  printf("%f ",(float) k);
k++;
}
```

Comment: Note that `K` is a `float`.

Comment: ha? that's not even half an answer to the question